# idHttp : error 500 internal server when site is https

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, indy, indy10, idhttp

I am working on a project involving login and download, for more than 20 site, in some cases, the sites are very alike, even their structure is the same
i have encountered a problem recently, some of the same structured sites are `http` and some are `Https`, the `Http` ones are ok and work fine but the `Https` ones at the very first `post` return an error `500 internal server` when i try to login, the response code shows

> `for security reasons you can not access ...`

**do i need to change my approach with `https` sites ? how can i fix this ?**
**my code :**

```
mIdHttp := TIdHttp.create(nil);
mIdHttp.AllowCookies := true;
mIdHttp.HandleRedirects := true;
mIdHttp.Request.Charset := 'utf-8';
requestList.add('the post info from http analyzer');
mIdHttp.post('site login url', requestList, responseCode); // error happens here
```

*for privacy reasons i can not share the url for any of the sites*
**Edit :**
i did what was suggested about setting handler

```
LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
mIdHttp.IOHandler:=LHandler;
```

but it didn't work! (i also downloaded the two dll)

**New development :**
i just noticed the windows internet explorer cant open the site either!! and it returns an error :

```
Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 in Advanced settings and try connecting to somesite.com  again. If this error persists, contact your site administrator.
```

i think the **certificate for the site is a fake**, and if i go to the setting and uncheck the

```
check for publisher certifcate revocation
```

option in internet explorer, the site opens!, is this the reason i'm getting an error ? **how can i do the same to idHttp** ?

**Edit 2 (A New Site):**
*because the problem with this site is very similar to the previous one, i decided **not to create a new question** for this*

I'm getting an error `500` with a new site , when i try to manually go to the site and login i get an `This Connection is Untrusted` error in firefox and similar error in other browsers here is a picture o the firefox error :
[image]

I have already tried

```
LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
//LHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
LHandler.OnVerifyPeer := OnVerifyPeer;
mIdHttp.IOHandler := LHandler;  

function OnVerifyPeer(certificate: TIdX509; AOk: Boolean; Adepth:Integer; AError: Integer): boolean;
begin
  Result := true;
end;
```

but i still get the same error
i also should mention that in this particular case, using `idHttp.Get` **does not** cause any error, the error happens when i trying to `Post` for login.
one more thing, i use both `httpAnalyzer` and `fiddler`, but none of them can pick up the site `posts` or `gets` when i run my program (they **only** don't work when i use my program and i try to `post`and `get` for this particular site).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683127/delphi-idhttpssl on how to add SSL libraries to your project

Comment: Read "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example". If you can't provide such example, don't ask because nobody can guess what happens there  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: you dont' need to share the url, use a public site that support https like https://www.google.com. it will make the example easier for you test write test write faster.

Answer (score 0):

> i just noticed the windows internet explorer cant open the site either!! and it returns an error :
>
> Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 in Advanced settings and try connecting to somesite.com  again. If this error persists, contact your site administrator.

Enable the `sslvTLSv1`,  `sslvTLSv1_1`, and `sslvTLSv1_2` flags in the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions` property.

> i think the certificate for the site is a fake, and if i go to the setting and uncheck the
>
> check for publisher certifcate revocation
>
> option in internet explorer, the site opens!

Assign a handler to the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.OnVerifyPeer` event and have it return True for any certificate you want to accept.

Comment: i did `LHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];` and assigned a handler to OnVerifyPeer, but still the same error, using `Get` also gives the same error, i should i also mention that when i put a break point in `onVerifypeer` function, it never gets called, is that normal ?

Comment: i have encountered a very similar problem with a new site, please read the  Edit 2