# Change location of libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll to subfolder

Tags: delphi, ssl, openssl, delphi-xe5, indy10

I am using `Indy` to get JSON from a url address. My code is using `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` as `IOHandler` for `TIdHTTP`.

Both libraries `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` are present in the same folder as application executable.

These libraries are loaded automatically when they are needed as is written in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683553/1631551). This is working fine.

> You don't have to link them to anything. They're loaded automatically with plain old `LoadLibrary` when they're needed.

But I need to move these libraries to subfolder `Libs\`, but then they are not found and I receive exception `EIdOSSLCouldNotLoadSSLLibrary` with message: *Could not load SSL library.*

How can I force the application to know both libraries are not in the same folder but in subfolder `Libs\` and to be loaded from there when they are needed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13276924/937125

Comment: Thanks, this is it.

Comment: In case it is not clear from that link, the best solution is to use Indy's `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath()` function.